# Regex code for adding exceptions - python

Tags: python, regex

I've extracted a column with website links from a data frame to look for the websites:

```
csv_document = pd.read_csv(csv_doc)
tweets = csv_document.Tweet
    
count = {}

for tweet in tweets:
    matches = re.findall(r'http[s]?://([^\/]*)',tweet)
    for match in matches:
        count[match] = count.get(match,0) + 1
```

The regex code allow me to identify all the strings starting with 'http | https' + '://'.
Now I want to add in the regex code the way to avoid all the websaites starting with `www.` even if they have an `http://` or `https://`

I've tried with: `(?!www.)` :

```
    matches = re.findall(r'http[s]?://([^\/]*)(?!www.)',tweet)
```

I doesn't work. How can I add this exception?

I took a look to the regex website and couldn't get the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to put `(?!www\.)` after the protocol `https?://` : `r'https?://(?!www\.)([^\/ ]*)'`

Comment: @HaoWu, thanks! I wasn't that far. I thought it should be behind.